# Simple cheap foxhunting?

Tags: antenna, fox-hunt, outreach, equipment

I'm currently looking to do a foxhunt for a youth group, and need to keep it inexpensive and easy enough that it won't be impossible for those new to foxhunting and ham radio, but difficult enough that it will still be rewarding.

I'm a relatively new ham, so don't have any of the required equipment.  What is an inexpensive way to have a fox and two hunting setups?  Can I buy three cheap HTs, fabricate two antennas, and use a ham operator for the fox to avoid the need for additional electronics automation? Is there a cheaper or better set of equipment?  Note that the HTs would be under $100 [USD] total for 3 cheap dual band 4W units.  Any reason this wouldn't work, or would be frustrating for the hunters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine.

These cheap Chinese HTs don't have many bells and whistles, but they are decent radios especially with non-stock antennas.

For beginners I would start with some real simple scenarios and fairly open terrain.  You don't want a ton of multi-pathing scatter to confuse the new hunters.

See my answer to your other questions for some methods.

See the site http://www.homingin.com/ for lots of good information.